# How to fetch results without NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to fetch results from a class that is not a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is that why I am getting 0 results?

```
public static func getTopics() -> Array<ipTopic> {
    if (topics == nil) {
        var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<ipTopic>!
        let pc = CoreDataHub.getPersistentContainer()
        let blogIdeasFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<ipTopic>(entityName: "ipTopic")
        let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "ipTopicsClip", ascending: true)
        blogIdeasFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor]
        
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<ipTopic>(
            fetchRequest: blogIdeasFetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: pc.viewContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil)
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print("An error occurred")
            
        }
        print(fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count)
        for topic in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects! {
            topics.append(topic)
        }
    }
    return topics
}
```

Comment: if you do not want to use `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` then do not use `NSFetchedResultsController`. Use `NSFetchRequest` directly instead. I'd advise reading up more on core data, here is an article that may help but it is a little old. https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will creates new private queue and takes a block of code to run. This can live with your container or you can use container as argument

```
func read(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
    persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask {
        block($0)
    }
}
```

This is how you would use it

```
func fetchEvents() {
    read { context in
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()
        let events = try? context.fetch(request)
        print(events)
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this hang the UI because of perform and wait?

Comment: No, newBackgroundContext won't block. it is running on new context. If you have concern using that, I have updated my answer with use another API.